# How to append objects to the list that is an instance variable?

Tags: python, list, object, hash, graph

My program has a scheme with a connected lines determined by two points. I want to create some kind of graph and get adjacent points for each point when scheme initializes.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.adjacent_points=list()
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def __key(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__key())
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__key()==other.__key()
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(%s, %s)" % (self.x, self.y)

class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, point_1, point_2):
        self.point_1=point_1
        self.point_2=point_2

class Scheme(object):
    def __init__(self, element_list):
        self.element_list =element_list
        self.point_list=list()
        self.get_adjacent_points()
    def get_adjacent_points(self):
        self.point_list = list(set(p for l in self.element_list for p in (l.point_1, l.point_2)))
        for l in self.element_list:
            l.point_1.adjacent_points.append(l.point_2)
            l.point_2.adjacent_points.append(l.point_1)
```

I try to make simple scheme with two lines and three points.

```
point_list=list()

some_list = list()
some_list.append(Line(Point(0,0), Point(0,1)))
some_list.append(Line(Point(0,1), Point(0,2)))

scheme = Scheme(some_list)
```

It is supposed that point with coordinates (0,1) has two adjacent points:

```
>>> print(scheme.point_list[0])
Point(0, 1)
>>> print(scheme.point_list[0].adjacent_points)
[Point(0, 0)]
```

But it has  only one. Why?

Comment: why would you expect it to have two adjacent points when your for loop inside of `get_adjacent_points` only appends the other point in the line to each points `adjacent_points` list?

Comment: `adjacent_points` should probably be a set, not a list

Comment: FYI, you could save yourself some boilerplate by making `Point` inherit from a `collections.namedtuple`. `class Point(namedtuple('Point', 'x y')):`, `def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):`, `self = super(Point, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`, `self.adjacent_points = []`, `return self`. After that, no need for `__init__`, `__key`, `__eq__`, `__hash__`, or `__repr__`, the `namedtuple` inheritance provided them for you. And the `x` and `y` of a `Point` become truly immutable, so you don't accidentally modify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it has only one. Why?

Because `Point(1, 0) is Point(1, 0)` returns false, therefore there are two separate lists of points adjacent to `1, 0`.

Possible workarounds:

1. reuse the same point object:

   ```
   p01 = Point(0,1)

   some_list = [
       Line(Point(0,0), p01))
       Line(p01, Point(0,2)))
   ]
   scheme = Scheme(some_list)
   ```
2. Implement `__new__`, and store a lookup table of all points found so far, so that `Point(1, 0) is Point(1, 0)` returns true.
3. Instead of storing data at `p.adjacent_points`, store it at `scheme.adjacent_points[p]`

Comment: +1 for the advanced solution using memoized `__new__`. It's not usually the best approach, but it's incredibly powerful when you need it. If I might add, it might make sense to use a `weakref.WeakValueDictionary` (mapping coordinates to realized `Point` objects) so if no references to a `Point` remain it gets cleaned up automatically.

Comment: Does it turn out that each point before creating should "know" what the scheme owns it? But schemes create only after initializing of points and lines. It is going to be some kind of recursion.

Comment: @hopheylalaley: If you plan to have multiple schemes around, I don't think points should keep track of which scheme owns them - that's the job of the scheme

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the instance of Point(0,1) in the first list is not the same as the instance in the second list, even though they share co-ordinates. You used a set to construct `point_list`, so duplicate Points will be filtered out, but you haven't used that in any way to set the adjacent points.

Comment: could you advice any way for solving the problem?